# USB connector durability: plug vs socket

Tags: usb, connector, usb-device, durability

I've been searching for information about USB connectors durability and I have found those numbers:

- Type-A: 1,500 plug-unplug cycles
- Mini-A: 1,000 plug-unplug cycles
- Mini-B: 5,000 plug-unplug cycles
- Micro-B: 10,000 plug-unplug cycles
- Type-C: 10,000 plug-unplug cycles

What this data is lacking is information about which side of the connector has this durability. For example fragile bending parts were intentionally moved in micro-B from socket to plug to put wear on cheap cables instead of soldered elements. Does it mean, that after 10,000 cycles only the plug will fail? When will the socket wear off? If the numbers describe the more durable side, is there any data about type-A socket? Usually it's permanently soldered into expensive hardware, but has waring spring mechanism, so that seems important.

Comment: I was appalled when I first saw the micro connector, its size, but apparently it fixes the problem with the mini, which wears preferentially on the socket. The micro wears on the plug, sparing the socket, IIRC.

Comment: Cycle life is only one aspect of durability. The other thing is response to side loads, torque loads and excessive insertion force, etc. Just something to keep in mind. These forces typically cannot be transferred through the connector to the PCB. They have to be transferred to the plastic housing around the USB jack.

Answer (score 2):

Just get to digikey and search for connectors, then check out the datasheets:

Example 1: micro B receptacle: 10000 cycles
http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/amphenol-fci/10118192-0001LF/609-4613-2-ND/2785387

Example 2: micro B plug: 10000 cycles
http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/hirose-electric-co-ltd/ZX40-B-5S-UNIT(31)/H125260-ND/5994726

Example 3: micro B plug, different manufacturer: 1500 cycles
http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/keystone-electronics/941/36-941-ND/2745653

Comment: Does it mean, that the 3rd example is not USB standard compliant?